# File not found when include external file from argument.[Bash]

Tags: bash, shell-script

I must be missing something about include external file to my bash file.

In my scenario I have the following command

```
sh exec.sh env_local.conf ebis_tag
```

It showed the error

> exec.sh: line 30: .: env_local.conf: file not found

My following **exec.sh** script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage_exit() {
        echo "Usage: $0 [-b] env_file_path project_name" 1>&2
        exit 1
}

# default BANG_RUNNING="FALSE"
BANG_RUNNING="FALSE"

while getopts b OPT
do
  case $OPT in
    b) BANG_RUNNING="TRUE" ;;
    ¥?) usage_exit;
  esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
  echo $#;
  usage_exit;
fi

# import env_file
# CORE_HOST
# REF_HOST
# ADMASTER_HOST
. $1
```

**exec.sh** and **env_local.config** are in same directory

```
[root@6d4f1e2363eb makedb]# ls -l
total 81
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 ftp  3381 Mar 14 09:03 admaster.sql
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 ftp  1675 Mar 29 03:02 ebisdata.sql
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 ftp 51278 Mar 29 02:16 ebis.sql
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 ftp    83 Mar 29 02:18 env_local.conf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 ftp    93 Mar 14 09:03 env_stg.conf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 ftp  7233 Mar 29 03:01 exec.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 ftp  5854 Mar 14 09:03 README.md
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 ftp 10481 Mar 14 09:03 refdb.sql
drwxrwxrwx 1 1000 ftp     0 Mar 14 09:03 update
[root@6d4f1e2363eb makedb]#
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the script with `sh`, not bash. (`sh` might be `bash`, but when run as `sh`, it operates under different rules.)

When sourcing a file with `. something`, if `something` is not an absolute or relative path but just a filename, then [for a POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot):

> If file does not contain a `<slash>`, the shell shall use the search
>   path specified by `PATH` to find the directory containing file. Unlike
>   normal command search, however, the file searched for by the dot
>   utility need not be executable. If no readable file is found, a
>   non-interactive shell shall abort; an interactive shell shall write a
>   diagnostic message to standard error, but this condition shall not be
>   considered a syntax error.

Bash additionally looks for the file in the current directory as well. Run the script with `bash`, not `sh`, or do `./exec.sh` so that shebang (which is `#!/bin/bash`) is used. Otherwise give a path to the file

```
sh exec.sh ./env_local.config ebis_tag
```

Comment: I have resolved my issue. Thank you very much!!!